# Custom JS Interfere with Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have noticed once I added custom JS to my SharePoint page, one of my workflows stopped working (it sends email alerts). I checked it in Designer and it says no errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is client side while workflows are server side. It therefore can not interfere with a workflow.

Comment: That is what I figured, for some reason this workflow just stopped working out of the blue. Nothing was changed, it will not send email alerts anymore, it says it completes but nothing happens with 0 error.

Comment: You probably need to check the logic of the workflow e.g. are all the fields that are required completed etc